# How to display splash screen when Office js add in load?

Tags: reactjs, office-js, office-addins

I am working with office js add-in with react and typescript. I want to display a splash screen while add-in render. also, I have installed script labs add-in which display the correct splash screen with logo and text as "Code ● Run ● Share".I want exact similar but I can't find on google anything similar. I would be grateful for any help you are able to provide.
I have added an image so more it's clear my requirement

[image]

here is my code snippet.

```
import "office-ui-fabric-react/dist/css/fabric.min.css";
import App from "./components/App";
import { AppContainer } from "react-hot-loader";
import { initializeIcons } from "office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Icons";
import { initializeFileTypeIcons } from "@fluentui/react-file-type-icons";
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";
/* global document, Office, module, require */

initializeIcons();
initializeFileTypeIcons();

let isOfficeInitialized = false;

const title = "Task Pane Add-in Example";

const render = (Component) => {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <AppContainer>
      <Component title={title} isOfficeInitialized={isOfficeInitialized} />
    </AppContainer>,
    document.getElementById("container")
  );
};

/* Render application after Office initializes */
Office.initialize = () => {
  isOfficeInitialized = true;
  render(App);
};

if ((module as any).hot) {
  (module as any).hot.accept("./components/App", () => {
    const NextApp = require("./components/App").default;
    render(NextApp);
  });
}
```

Comment: Please add more detail about what you expect to see and what you actually see.

Comment: normally it displays when add-in load in the first time in excel web

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by removing rendering of the App component from the Office.initialize function. We want to have a loading page *while* Office initializes. To do so, we can render the App and move our logic for whether Office has loaded inside of the App component.

First, lets update the Component component to not pass the title or isOfficeInitialized props:

```
//let isOfficeInitialized = false;

//const title = "Task Pane Add-in Example";

const render = (Component) => {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <AppContainer>
      <Component />
    </AppContainer>,
    document.getElementById("container")
  );
};
```

Next, let's render App:

```
render(App);
```

Within **App.tsx**, let's make updates to comment out the exported AppProps (left for future reference) and export an isLoading boolean variable as part of AppState. We will also set a new const for our title:

```
export interface AppProps {
  //title: string;
  //isOfficeInitialized: boolean;
}


export interface AppState {
    isLoading: boolean;
}

const title = "Outlook Add-In Title";


export default class App extends React.Component<AppProps, AppState> {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.state = {
        isLoading: true,
    };
  }

    componentDidMount() {

        Office.onReady(() => {
            this.setState({
                isLoading: false
            });

        });
  }
```

We've added logic to our **componentDidMount** method to execute the **Office.onReady()** method, which is recommended by Microsoft: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/initialize-add-in. When Office is ready, we will set the isLoading state to false.

Within our App render function, we will return conditionals for what is presented:

```
 render() {
    
      //const { title, isOfficeInitialized } = this.props;
      return (
          this.state.isLoading
              ? (<div>Loading...</div>)
              : (<div className="ms-welcome">
                  <AppropriateAppComponent(s) />
                 </div>)
              )
  }
}
```

If the state for isLoading is being set to true too quickly (i.e. not enough time for your loading animation to complete), add use setTimeout to control the amount of time before isLoading is set to true:

```
componentDidMount() {

    Office.onReady(() => {

        // set the state within setTimeout for 5000 ms (5s)
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.setState({
                isLoading: false
            });
        }, 5000)
    });
}
```